# pass array of objects to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I created a progress bar component that takes props like color, height, value and max. Right now it shows one sigle progress bar and i am trying to group progress bar and group them by color. Here is my component

```
const ProgressBar = ({
  heightSize,
  value,
  max,
  ...customProps
}) => {
  const classes = classNames([
    'my-ProgressBar',
    { [`my-ProgressBar--${heightSize}`]: heightSize },
    customProps.className,
  ]);

  const normalizedValue = (value / max) * 100;

  return (
    <progress
      {...customProps}
      style={{ color: customProps.color }}
      className={classes}
      max={100}
      value={normalizedValue}
      aria-valuemax={100}
      aria-valuemin={0}
      aria-valuenow={normalizedValue}
      tabIndex="-1"
    />);
};
```

I am trying to update this component so that if i pass an array to this component, it'll return grouped progress bar. Here is one of my failed attempts.

```
const ProgressBar = (groups) => {
        const GroupProgressBar= groups.map((group) => (
        <div key={group.color}>
          color: {group.color},
          heightSize: {group.height},
          value: {group.value},
          color: {group.color}          
        </div>
      ));
            return (
              <progress
                {...customProps}
                style={{ color: group.color }}
                className={classes}
                max={100}
                value={normalizedValue}
                aria-valuemax={100}
                aria-valuemin={0}
                aria-valuenow={normalizedValue}
                tabIndex="-1"
              />);
        });
```

How do i udpate my component so it will work on groups?

Comment: grouped progress bar means, each progress bar for array element correct?

Comment: @Mayank Shukla. Yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use map to create progress bar for each entry of array, then return from the component.

Write it like this:

```
const ProgressBar = ({groups, heightSize}) => {

    let heightSize = 10;   /*calculate here*/

    const GroupProgressBar = groups.map((group, i) => (
          <progress
              key = {i}
              {...customProps}
              heightSize = {heightSize}
              style={{ color: group.color }}
              className={classes}
              max={100}
              value={group.value}
              aria-valuemax={100}
              aria-valuemin={0}
              aria-valuenow={normalizedValue}
              tabIndex="-1"
          />
        )
    )

    return <div> {GroupProgressBar} </div>
}
```

Check the [**DOCs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) for more details.

**Update:**

See we can pass any no of props from parent component, **[props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)** is an object that contains all the data. In functional component, we need to write it like this:

```
const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
}
```

Here props will contain all the data and method passed, you can access any passed value by `props.keyName`, pass the height and groups from parent and access them by `props.groups` and `props.height`.

Another way is:

```
const ProgressBar = ({groups, heightSize}) => {
    console.log(groups, heightSize);
}
```

this is nothing but the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), now we can use these values directly by groups and heightSize.

**Note:** Assign the unique key to each progress bar inside map, i used item index but that is not a good way, so assign some unique value from group object.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i am deriving heightSize based on the value passed. I have a class .my-ProgressBar in css. so based the height small, medium, high i am getting the bar size. How can i do that?

Comment: sorry didn't get that, you want to calculate the height for each entry or it will be fixed for all the array entries?

Comment: np. It'll be fixed for all the array entries. Thanks for asking that question, that cleared one of question :)

Comment: Thanks. Can we make heightSize as separate prop so the existing css class will return the size based on what user pass?

Comment: don't forget to set `key` property on those `progress` components.

Comment: @Brandon thanks forgot that part updated the answer :)

Comment: @User7354632781 *Can we make heightSize as separate prop?* means you want to pass its value from parent component?

Comment: @MayankShukla Sorry i am new to jsx. yes I want to pass height as a separate prop along with groups. Thanks for key update. i am passing color as key since thats unique for each group. Can i do this,      `const ProgressBar = (groups, height) => {

  const classes = classNames([
    'my-ProgressBar',
    { [`my-ProgressBar--${heightSize}`]: heightSize },
    customProps.className,
  ]);`

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if you have any doubt :)